# Fixed field of automorphisms determined by $t\mapsto at+b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Suppose $E=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, the field of rational functions in a transcendental $t$ over the finite field of $p$ elements. Suppose $G$ is the group of field automorphisms fixing $\mathbb{F}_p$ pointwise and sending $t\mapsto at+b$ where $a\neq 0$. What is the characterization of the fixed field $\operatorname{Inv}(G)$?

I know that $[E:\operatorname{Inv}(G)]=|G|=p(p-1)$. I've been trying to find some $u$ in terms of $t$ fixed by $G$ such that $t$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $p(p-1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p(u)$ in hopes of getting the equation
$$ p(p-1)\leq[E:\operatorname{Inv}(G)][\operatorname{Inv}(G):\mathbb{F}_p(u)]=[E:\mathbb{F}_p(u)]\leq p(p-1).$$
Since $[E:\operatorname{Inv}(G)]=p(p-1)$, this would give $[\operatorname{Inv}(G):\mathbb{F}_p(u)]=1$.

Taking $u=t^p-t$, I observed that $u$ is fixed by all automorphisms sending $t\mapsto t+b$. With Lubin's help, I realized the set of all such automorphisms $t\mapsto t+b$ forms a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $p$. I've been able to show that the fixed field $\operatorname{Inv}(H)=\mathbb{F}_p(u)$. By the fundamental theorem,
$$
[G:H]=p-1=[\operatorname{Inv}(H):\operatorname{Inv}(G)]
$$
and so $\mathbb{F}_p(u)/\operatorname{Inv}(G)$ is a normal extension of degree $p-1$. However, I'm stumped using this information to actually determine $\operatorname{Inv}(G)$.

Thanks. By the way, this is roughly from page 243 of *Basic Algebra I* by Jacobson, which I'm self-studying.

Comment: Can you identify some nice subgroups of your group? Find the corresponding fixed fields? You may be able to take the intersection of these, though this isn’t always an easy task.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks, I found $H$ to be the subgroup of automoprhisms $t\mapsto t+b$ for any $b\in\mathbb{F}_p$. This is a subgroup of order $p$, with fixed field $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p-t)$. I'll see if I can find any others.

Comment: Good, and the subgroup you found was normal, right? So the intermediate field you found is normal over the fixed field, of degree $p-1$, and you have the $p-1$-th roots of unity in all fields, so the intermediate field is gotten from the fixed field by adjoining a $p-1$-th root of something or other, right? This ought to lead to the fixed field itself...

Comment: Another hint: often you can find the fixed field of a group by taking a nice thing upstairs and calculating its norm down to the fixed field. It’s surprising how often this works.

Comment: Thanks @Lubin I'm stuck following your first suggestion. I verified that $H\unlhd G$, and I see that $[G:H]=p-1=[\mathbb{F}_p(t^p-t):\operatorname{Inv}(G)]$ is a normal extension. What does it mean to say I have the $p-1$th roots of unity in all fields if I'm not working in $\mathbb{C}$? So you're saying $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p-t)=\operatorname{Inv}(G)(?)$. I don't know what $p-1$ root I'm looking to adjoin.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{Inv}(G)=\mathbb{F}_p((t^p-t)^{p-1})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that $\operatorname{Inv}(G)=\mathbb F_p((t^p-t)^{p-1})$ and this is not hard to prove. As you observed $|G|=p(p-1)$. This shows that $[E:\operatorname{Inv}(G)]=p(p-1)$. On the other side, it's obvious that $\mathbb F_p((t^p-t)^{p-1})\subseteq \operatorname{Inv}(G)$. But $[E:\mathbb F_p((t^p-t)^{p-1})]=p(p-1)$, and we are done.